# Lazy load services dynamically

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-dependency-injection

After watching the Laravell Nova presentation I wanted to create similar functionality to Lenses in my own app.

I have the following concepts:

- Entity: Standard Doctrine Entity
- Resource: A class that describes a resource including the target entity and available lenses.
- Lens: Has an method `apply(Request $request, QueryBuilder $qb)` that allow you to modify the `QueryBuilder` based on the `Request`.

The goal is to define all `Lenses` as a service and then somehow assign them to a `Resource`. This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

**Attempt 1: Directly inject the `Lenses` into the resource**

ProjectResource.php

```
<?php

class ProjectResource
{
    protected $lenses = [];

    public function __construct(
        ProjectRepository $repository,
        LensInterface $activeProjectLens,
        LensInterface $starredProjectLens
    ) {
        $this->lenses = [
            $activeProjectLens,
            $starredProjectLens
        ];
    }

    public function getLenses() {
        return $this->lenses;
    }
}
```

The downside of this is that each `Lens` service is instantiated and needs to be defined manually

**Attempt 2: Inject tagged `Lenses` into the resource**

In my `services.yaml` tag the services and assign them as an argument to the resource:

```
  App\Lens\ActiveProjectLens:
    tags: ['resource.project.lens']

  App\Lens\StarredProjectLens:
    tags: ['resource.project.lens']

  App\Resource\ProjectResource:
    arguments:
      $lenses: !tagged resource.project.lens
```

ProjectResource.php

```
<?php

class ProjectResource
{
    protected $lenses = [];

    public function __construct(
        ProjectRepository $repository,
        iterable $lenses
    ) {
        $this->lenses = $lenses;
    }

    public function getLenses() {
        return $this->lenses;
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is every `Lens` service and Resource must be tagged and cannot be an auto-configured service.

**Attempt 3: Add a compiler pass **

I attempted to add the `process()` method to the `Kernel` but I didn't get too far with that.

---

My goal is to define a list of services somehow in the `Resource` and have them injected. Is there any established pattern for this?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with the tags seems good. Symfony provides a way to automatically add tags to classes that implement a certain interface: [Interface-based service configuration](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-simpler-service-configuration#interface-based-service-configuration).

To use that you have to do the following:

1. If you don't already have one, create an interface (e.g. `App\Lens\LensInterface`) and let your lens classes implement the interface.
2. In your `services.yaml` file add this config:

```
services:
    // ...

    _instanceof:
        App\Lens\LensInterface:
            tags: ['resource.project.lens']

    App\Resource\ProjectResource:
        arguments:
            $lenses: [!tagged resource.project.lens]

    // ...
```

Then every class implementing your LensInterface would be injected into the ProjectResource without having to explicitly configure every single lens.